# Java BounceBall Ball Move

Tags: java, swing

I have a question. 
I'm not getting make the balls escape from the mouse pointer. 
All balls go to the left corner when the mouse pointer enters the screen. 
What am I doing wrong? Any tips??

My full code:
[Java BounceBall mouse event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25816205/1898543)

Or

http://ideone.com/vTGzb7

Method with problem:

```
public void move(Ball ball, Point mouse) {

    try {
        Point p = ball.getLocation();
        Point speed = ball.getSpeed();
        Dimension size = ball.getSize();

        int vx = speed.x;
        int vy = speed.y;

        int x = p.x;
        int y = p.y;

        // ----------------------
        if (mouse != null) {

            int xDistance = Math.abs(x + size.width - mouse.x);
            int yDistance = Math.abs(y + size.height - mouse.y);

            if (xDistance < yDistance) {
                if (x + size.width < mouse.x) {
                    if (vx > 0) {
                        vx *= -1;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (vx > 0) {
                        vx *= -1;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (y + size.height < mouse.y) {
                    if (vy > 0) {
                        vy *= -1;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (vy > 0) {
                        vy *= -1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        // ----------------------

        if (x + vx < 0 || x + size.width + vx > getParent().getWidth()) {
            vx *= -1;
        }
        if (y + vy < 0
                || y + size.height + vy > getParent().getHeight()) {
            vy *= -1;
        }
        x += vx;
        y += vy;

        ball.setSpeed(new Point(vx, vy));
        ball.setLocation(new Point(x, y));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

For some balls it works fine.
They hit in the mouse pointer and change your direction.
But the majority goes to the corner of the screen.

Thank You.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minial Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: I ran the program, and movements seems to be random enough. Nice work by the way.

Comment: Do not know why it works for some and not for others.

Comment: Someone? Any tips???

Comment: The code where you determine whether to bounce off the cursor doesn't work. (Everything inside `if (mouse != null) { }`.) I can't tell how you want it to work. Also, your program is not thread safe.

Comment: @Radiodef He enters this if statement, but I could not identify because of the bubbles go to the top corner.

Comment: The balls do that because that's what the code does.

Comment: @Radiodef I do not understand. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved...

Problem: The bubbles were locked in the upper corner of the screen. And do not hit the mouse pointer.

Solution: I calculated the distance from the X and Y position relative to the bubble diameter and the mouse pointer. For collision.

```
int xDistance = Math.abs((x + (diameter / 2)) - mouse.x);
int yDistance = Math.abs((y + (diameter / 2)) - mouse.y);
```

Then calculated the X and Y radius of the bubbles.

```
int radiusX = (size.width / 2);
int radiusY = (size.height / 2);
```

Finally, I changed the IF to check the relationship between the distance of the bubble radius. Changing your direction.

```
if (xDistance <= radiusX && yDistance <= radiusY) {
    if (xDistance < yDistance) {
        vx *= -1;
    } else {
        vy *= -1;
    }

    System.out.println("Hit!");
}
```

New Move Method:

```
public void move(Ball ball, Point mouse) {

    try {
        Point p = ball.getLocation();
        Point speed = ball.getSpeed();
        Dimension size = ball.getSize();

        int diameter = ball.dimeter;

        int vx = speed.x;
        int vy = speed.y;

        int x = p.x;
        int y = p.y;

        int radiusX = (size.width / 2);
        int radiusY = (size.height / 2);

        // ----------------------

        if (mouse != null) {
            int xDistance = Math.abs((x + (diameter / 2)) - mouse.x);
            int yDistance = Math.abs((y + (diameter / 2)) - mouse.y);

            System.out.printf("b(%d, %d) m(%d, %d) dx(%d, %d)\n", x, y,
                    mouse.x, mouse.y, (x + vx) - mouse.x, (y + vy)
                            - mouse.y);

            if (xDistance <= radiusX && yDistance <= radiusY) {

                if (xDistance < yDistance) {
                    vx *= -1;
                } else {
                    vy *= -1;
                }

                System.out.println("Hit");
            }
        }

        if (x + vx < 0 || x + size.width + vx > getParent().getWidth()) {
            vx *= -1;
        }
        if (y + vy < 0
                || y + size.height + vy > getParent().getHeight()) {
            vy *= -1;
        }

        x += vx;
        y += vy;

        ball.setSpeed(new Point(vx, vy));
        ball.setLocation(new Point(x, y));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the problem and what was the solution?